# What should I do if the head of column with space in R?

Tags: r

I import data (daily snow Depth data )from an excel. 
But this dataset has a lot of space in it, especially the spaces also contained in the head. Like the heads shows bellow:

```
GHCN ID    Station Name     County      Mar 1      Mar 2      Mar 3 ......
```

Thus, when I try to set up a subset by the name of the 2nd column if it is equal to "Station Name", like this:

```
Boston_snow <- subset(MA_snow,Station Name == "BOSTON",select =       c(3/1/2017:3/31/2017))
```

R returned me an error:
Error: unexpected symbol in "Boston_snow <- subset(MA_snow,Station Name"

But if I eliminate the space in code:

```
Boston_snow <- subset(MA_snow,StationName == "BOSTON",select =       c(3/1/2017:3/31/2017))
```

Still an error occurred:
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'StationName' not found

So, what should I do? I mean, maybe either to eliminate all the spaces in my excel or use some command that can work well with spaces are fine to me. But I have no idea on them, especially the later option.

Sincerely hope can get an answer. Thank you soooo much for your help.

Comment: Thanks to @ Gaël Marziou 's suggestion. I corrected this now.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found a space replace way for that:

```
MA_snow2 <- as.data.frame(apply(MA_snow,2,function(x)gsub('\\s+', '_',x)))
```

This command will replace all the space by _ in my whole data frame.

Meanwhile, I realized that simply use the gsub command as follow does not work, because it just can work on a string:

```
MA_snow2 <- gsub("\\s", "_",MA_snow)
```

Thanks to @jwells all the same.